# Error/Success messages show wrong page and are not cleared

Tags: magento2, messages, magento-2.2.1

I'm on 2.2.1 with custom theme
when login failed, message showed up but are not cleared, it showed duplicate, and when login successfully, its still showing in account infomation page
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi @Dang Nguyen:  these many issue are cached in session that reason repeating

Comment: do you have any idea to help me fix that?

Comment: these message are set into session so check condition  whether that message is set or not if it is set then reset that message from session.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Override messages.js in this location:

**app/design/frontend/Mastering/itdesire/Magento_Theme/web/js/view/messages.js**

```
    /**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
define([
    'jquery',
    'uiComponent',
    'underscore',
    'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data',
    'jquery/jquery-storageapi'
], function ($, Component, _, customerData) {
    'use strict';

    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            cookieMessages: [],
            messages: []
        },

        /** @inheritdoc */
        initialize: function () {
            this._super();

            this.cookieMessages = $.cookieStorage.get('mage-messages');
            this.messages = customerData.get('messages').extend({
                disposableCustomerData: 'messages'
            });

            if (!_.isEmpty(this.messages().messages)) {
                customerData.set('messages', {});
            }

            $.cookieStorage.set('mage-messages', '');

            $(window).on('beforeunload', function () {
                $.cookieStorage.set('mage-messages', '');
            });

        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I already added this line before that's why it works fine in desktop, but I don't know why it didn't work on mobile devices(not emulator)