# Magento2: Session messages not removed properly - persist across multiple requests

Tags: magento2, error, frontend, messages

I have facing in cache issue in my magento 2 store here if i submit any form getting error and success message coming  when refresh page.i don't understand why this issue comes again and again .if any one facing same issue please suggest me and reply me as soon as

[image]

Comment: Maybe this link can help you: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/208110/error-success-messages-show-wrong-page-and-are-not-cleared/208167

Answer (score -1):

I have got the solution this code comment now

```
/*$(window).on('beforeunload', function () {
                $.cookieStorage.set('mage-messages', '');
            });  */
```

added the code here

```
setTimeout(function()
        {
            jQuery( ".messages" ).html('');
        }, 50000);
```

its working for now  in backend side cache always enable

Comment: in which file you added the above code