# Magento 2 : Duplicate notification message on Mobile device

Tags: magento2, messages, success-message, notification

I followed this link to remove all my duplicate messages.

> [Error/Success messages show wrong page and are not cleared](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/208110/error-success-messages-show-wrong-page-and-are-not-cleared/208167)

It worked for desktop chrome. But when test it on actual device like `android` and `iphone`
It shows duplicate as well as previous all messages.

[image]

It works perfectly for desktop chrome/safari.
**How to fix this?**

Comment: Which Magento2 version you using?

Comment: my Magento version is 2.30

Comment: Have you tried to clear Mobile devices cache?

Comment: @AmitNaraniwal yes I did, doesn't work, same issue

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution :

copy `vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/web/js/view/messages.js` to your **theme** file, and at the end of **initialize function add**:

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
    $.cookieStorage.set('mage-messages', '');
});
```

Reference : https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/10107

Comment: I already added this line before that's why it works fine in desktop, but I don't know why it didn't work on mobile devices(not emulator)